# Is this data cable able to charge a device?

Tags: cable, mobile-phone, charger

Is this data cable able to charge a mobile phone device?
http://www.amazon.co.uk/USB-Data-cable-Samsung-SGH-E250/dp/B002TK0K68

(Sorry, I'm not a native english speaker - does `Power supply via USB port` mean that I can charge a device with it?)

Thank you,
Sina

Comment: some cables are power only, and some are signal only. yes I believe that the cable you are looking at will charge your phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be a bit more accurate (and understanding that the question translated to English might not reflect your true question) - No. No cable can charge a device. What this cable will do is connect two devices using a USB cable; a host with a (pretty much universal) USB 'A' female jack connector and a 'client' with a micro 'B' (pretty much the new standard for USB mobile devices).

Assuming that the host device can supply enough amperage that the client device demands for charging its battery, then using this cable connected as such can charge your device. Note that some mobile devices require more amperage for charging than the USB 2.0 specification (0.5amps) - notably most apple mobile devices. USB 3.1 increased this limit to 5amps. This is why charging on PC's and Mac's doesn't always work.

If you are using a stand alone charging device whose only purpose is to supply power charging, the 0.5 amp limit is ignored. Most devices will use the data lines of the USB socket to detect if this is possible. [This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Serial_Bus#Charging_ports) is a good summary of USB charging.

You didn't ask about data transfer, but these types of inexpensive cables sometimes are poor data cables - suffering from line interference causing enough transmissions errors that result in failure. A rough visual assessment of the cable's diameter indicates how well insulated the data lines are. Something very thin aren't insulated and might be poor data cables.

Answer (score 0):

Most cables you buy which connect your phone to a computer will also charge your phone. This one specifically mentions in the page it will charge your phone. So the answer to your question is yes it will charge your device.